# How to detect audio types playable by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, audio, html5-audio

I'm working on a project that uses browser fingerprinting, one of the techniques I've seen used before finds all audio types that the browser or user can play, how would I do this with javascript?

I know that you can use HTMLMediaElement.canPlaytype(), but this is only for specific cases , I want to know every single type playable. When testing my fingerprint on AmiUnique or Browserleaks you can see some audio types like:

```
audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"
```

I can't find anything on google which lists all audio types other wise I would just use canPlayType for every option. Does anyone know any other methods?

Comment: "I'm working on a project that uses browser fingerprinting"  Please, don't.  :-(  Browser devs are already wrecking useful APIs because people abuse them for fingerprinting.  Don't add to the problem.

Comment: I'm actually trying to find the method on how this fingerprinting takes place. I want to be able to give my users the option to enable more privacy in their browser.

Comment: You don't need this, you can just add multiple sources to your audio tag (for example, an `mp3` as the first source will be used by any browser that supports `MP3`, but if the browser doesn't support `MP3` and you add an `FLAC` file, it would use the `FLAC` file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no method for enumerating what's supported on a system.  This isn't really all that possible, nor useful, as there are an enormous number of permutations of containers and codecs.  Additionally, it isn't even possible to definitively determine whether or not something is going to successfully play ahead of time, as media often has bitstream quirks or hardware has compatibility issues.  (Try to play HE-AACv2 on some iPhones... to the software, it works, but to the listener it will sound broken!)

The best you can do is take a list of items you want to test for.  There is no definitive list of *all possible permutations*, so you're going to have to pick some.

Probably a good place to start is the unit tests for Chromium:

- [MediaSource.isTypeSupported](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/master/LayoutTests/http/tests/media/media-source/mediasource-is-type-supported.html)
- [audio.canPlayType FLAC](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/master/LayoutTests/media/media-can-play-flac-audio.html)
- [audio.canPlayType MPEG Audio](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/master/LayoutTests/media/media-can-play-mpeg-audio.html)
- [video.canPlayType MPEG-4 Video](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/master/LayoutTests/media/media-can-play-mpeg4-video.html)
- [video.canPlayType Ogg](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/master/LayoutTests/media/media-can-play-ogg.html)
- [audio.canPlayType WAV Audio](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/master/LayoutTests/media/media-can-play-wav-audio.html)
- [video.canPlayType WebM](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/master/LayoutTests/media/media-can-play-webm.html)

Comment: I was starting to come to that conclusion, it looks like mediarecorder.canPlay would be the best way to go and to pick the most common audiotypes, thanks.

Comment: @Devbro Tests for MediaRecorder are unrelated to what can be played.  That's for what can be encoded.

Comment: I meant isTypeSupported here is the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/isTypeSupported

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t look properly, when on page of [canPlayType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType) there is link to [MediaCapabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaCapabilities). This will give you most information you can get. There is no list or anything but it provides much more than `canPlayType`.

Comment: That still doesn't let me find all the supported audio. A function that would allow me to enumerate through all supported codecs/audio types is what i'm looking for

Comment: @Devbro No, it won't browsers list all capabilities of user's computer, as it would help tracker identify computers even in anonymous mode. You need to know what are you looking for...